# Google Cloud Datastote: Groupby queries and complex aggregations

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-datastore

I am evaluating [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) for a simple application where the data will be inserted/updated then the group of time-range based aggregation queries will be executed.

The cloud datastore documentation has basic [query language description.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#product_name_short_query_interface)

How can we do `groupby` queries on multiple fields using cloud data store query?

Also, does cloud datastore provides complex aggregation queries or only simple get, sort and project queries can be executed?

**Sample Data:**

```
{
    "name": "user1",
    "state": "V",
    "status": "verified"
} {
    "name": "user2",
    "state": "C",
    "status": "non-verified"
} {
    "name": "user3",
    "state": "T",
    "status": "non-verified"
} {
    "name": "user4",
    "state": "M",
    "status": "verified"
}
```

**Expected Results:**

```
{ "user" : "user4", "count" : 1 }
{ "user" : "user3", "count" : 1 }
{ "user" : "user2", "count" : 1 }
{ "user" : "user1", "count" : 1 }
```

I am planning to execute more complex aggregation sort of the [mongodb aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) provides

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do that in Datastore. Datastore query language is pretty poor, I'd say.
There are no aggregation queries from Mongo world (or joins from SQL world).
Also, no such grouping functionality as you saw in mongoDb. Only distinct on query, but it just returning first record that contains provided properties list (projection) https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries.

For data structures that has relations I would choose another option (SQL or Mongo), instead of Datastore. 
Datastore, I guess is best for other tasks and strongly non relational data.

You can always use it, but remember then, that all data aggregations and joins the will be done on code level, instead of db level, that, I believe you'd like to avoid.